# Getting local server broadcasting again after wifi disconnect

Tags: networking

Currently I can connect to my pi through the wifi that it's broadcasting and then 
I change a few things through ssh and get it connected to my home wifi (which closes the wifi that the pi is broadcasting. My problem is that I can't get the local wifi from the pi to broadcast again after I disconnect it from the home wifi unless I reboot.

What I've been doing is changing the network interfaces file to have dhcp and the home wifi name and password and then

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 
sudo ifup wlan0
```

At this point, my pi is connected to the home wifi. However, when I change my network interfaces file back exactly how it was before and then repeat the ifdown/ipup commands, my local wifi doesn't broadcast.

The purpose is to basically get the local wifi working again in case of a wrong login so I guess if there is a way to just check if the credentials would work from within the command line, that'd be a huge help too.

**UPDATE:**

I noticed after some digging that the wifi dongle is actually turning off when I change my /etc/network/interfaces back to my local wifi settings and then then sudo ifdown wlan0/ ifup wlan0 (or at least isn't blinking green anymore). It does blink again when I ifdown wlan0, but when I ifup wlan0, it turns back off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured out through way too many attempts is to bring down the wlan0

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
```

and then change your /etc/network/interfaces file back from

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
     wpa-ssid "network"
     wpa-psk "password"
```

to the static version

```
iface wlan0 inet static 
     address 192.168.xx.x
     netmask 255.255.255.0
```

(This address and netmask could change depending on what you have)

and then bring your wlan0 back up

```
sudo ifup wlan0
```

Now we want to reset the hostapd. I'm assuming it reassociates itself with the ip? Maybe someone else could explain that reason further. I just know it worked for me.

```
sudo service hostapd stop
sudo service hostapd start
```

Then, it should be broadcasting local wifi again!